# Evaluating MATLAB Quadratic rBform

Tags: matlab, spline

I have created a planar piecewise biarc curve in MATLAB using the `rscvn` function. I have been able to plot it as follows:

```
p = [0 1 2 3; 2 6 3 9];
B = rscvn(p)
fnplt(B)
hold on
scatter([0 1 2 3],[2 6 3 9]);
hold off
```

Unfortunately I can't for the life of me figure out how to evaluate the function `B` for an arbitrary position, say `2.6`.

How should I attempt this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can evaluate a function from the curve fitting toolbox using the `fnval` function.

See https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fnval.html

Example code

```
p = [0 1 2 3; 2 6 3 9];
B = rscvn(p);
fnval(B,2.6)
```

Output

```
ans =

    1.8526
    5.1884
```

**Edit** From your comment and the format of your data I assume you are actually looking to estimate a continuous function from your data. In that case you can use.

```
p = [0 1 2 3; 2 6 3 9];
C = csapi(p(1,:), p(2,:));
fnplt(C)
hold on
scatter([0 1 2 3],[2 6 3 9]);
hold off

fnval(C,2.6)
```

Output

```
ans =

    4.4960
```

Comment: In this case, what do both answers mean? I would only expect a single solution...

Comment: Your code computes an interpolation between the points (0,2),(1,6),(2,3),(3,9) in order. The evaluate function returns the result of the interpolation between the points where `fnval(B,0) = [0;2]`, `fnval(B,2) = [1;6]`, `fnval(B,4)=[2,3]`, `fnval(B,6)=[3;9]` any parameter outside the range [0,6] will result in (0,0) (the function doesn't extrapolate). So when you give the value 2.6 it compute a location on the curve somewhere between the second and third points, i.e. between (1,6) and (2,3).

Comment: @user3185748 I made an edit on the answer in anticipation of what you are looking for.

Comment: Ahh, that is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much, in fact, the function you suggested offers a much better solution!